# Float inaccurate rounding in Mongodb with CS driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When I save the float number into MongoDB using csharp driver it is not saved accurately. If my number is 1504.57 I expect the database will have the same number but for some reason it become 1504.56994628906 (with Double type in MongoDB). What's going on? How to keep data accurately?

My object keep all the field as object types and cast them on the fly depending on the type, for example:

```
 this.Values[i] = float.Parse(this.Values[i].ToString());
```

Maybe is it the reason of this strange behavior? But after casting this.Values[i] is pretty accurate and it's spoiled only in database.
Thanks

Update. 
The class that incapsulates data:
public class TransferredData
    {
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

```
    public class Data
    {
        public List<Object> Values { get; set; }
        public DateTypes DataType { get; set; }
        public void CastToType()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Values.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (this.DataType == DateTypes.Date)
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(this.Values[i].ToString());
                    this.Values[i] = dt.ToUniversalTime().Date;
                }
                else if (this.DataType == DateTypes.Other)
                {
                    this.Values[i] = this.Values[i].ToString();
                }
                else if (this.DataType == DateTypes.Reading)
                {
                    this.Values[i] = float.Parse(this.Values[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

I use Object type because I don't know which actual type it could be. So, just before doing upsert I fill up this class by data and then call Cast method.

```
Then I save it into db:
data = new TransferredData();
...
data.Values[1] = "1504.57"; // Because the input is always string
data.CastToType(); // Here data.Values[1] = 1504.57 - cool
TransferredDataCollection.Save<TransferredData>(data, SafeMode.True);
```

After this moment, looking into database... it's 1504.56994628906

Comment: Can you provide code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I believe this is to do with the binary representation of floats themselves, a good way of doing it is to either *10 or store it as a string or in the double helper if there is one for your driver

Comment: While the posts about floating point inaccuracies are correct, I think the fact that you're using a `float` instead of a `double` in your code is likely making it much worse.  Try changing your code to use `double` instead.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I already tried this one too. Even when it's double in the code during debug it's still 1504.57, but as soon as it' put into database it became inaccurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IEEE 754 floating point formats cannot represent every single number accurately. As such your issue cannot be avoided and works as intended.

You should not **ever** use floating point formats if you need absolute guarantees that input=output while you cannot guarantee that the input can be accurately represented by the used floating point format.

Most people run into these problems when they try to store monetary values in floats which is universaly accepted to be an extremely bad idea. If you need to store monetary values save it as an integer value, usually as cents.

Answer (score 0):

i imagine this has something to do with the representatioh of 1504.57 as a double precision floating point #.

perhaps there are a couple options, one being to round off the excess digits and the other being to store cents instead of dollars if the number is a currency #.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo all the above comments that floating point numbers often exhibit interesting rounding errors when converted from decimal to binary and back.

In your particular case, the rounding errors are being introduced by the C# language itself, not by the C# driver. MongoDB does not natively support single precision floating point numbers, so your C# float values are being converted by the C# driver to doubles before being sent to the database. It is during this conversion that the rounding errors occur.

Here's a small snippet of C# code that demonstrates how casting a float to a double introduces the rounding errors:

```
var f = (float)1504.57;
var d = (double)f;

Console.WriteLine(f);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

As others have recommended, if you must have 100% precision you should use some other data type than float or double.